# clicking "go to definition" in vscode use all my system ram

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am using vs-code for Python coding. now I have a big issue. when I set python Interpreter and right-click on anywhere in my code and click go to definition, all my ram used by vscode ms python extension. Is there any other setting I need to do to prevent it? I have to kill the process every time that happens!

Comment: All of your RAM??? How much is available???

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @TimothyG. 14 g of 16 g

Comment: @JialeDu what kinds of details? every code i run has this situation

Comment: Your machine model, vscode version, python extension version, etc. You can report issues on GitHub and get responses from developers.